# Get response of function assigned to variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, salesforce

How can I retrieve result of the function assigned to variable in JavaScript?

So I have this code calling `callback` variable.

```
var result =  sforce.interaction.searchAndGetScreenPopUrl('07411111111', '', '', callback);
```

And the `callback` variable is a function:

```
        var callback = function (response) {
            if (response.result) {
                return response.result;
            } else {
                return response.error;
            }
        };
```

But when I then do:

```
console.log(result);
```

I get:

```
undefined
```

So my question is how can I return response of the `callback` function so it's accessible from `result` variable.

Comment: @JeremyThille I am not making asynchronus call, this is not a duplicate...

Comment: If it has a callback, it is asynchronous.

Comment: You're calling a function with a callback, how's that not async?